# busqueda php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un buscador con un formulario normal y todo, pero en mi `bd` tengo algunas palabras con `ñ` y otras sin `ñ` por si el cliente lo ingresa mal.

El problema es que digamos busco la palabra `"estreñimiento"` no encuentra nada aun así este la palabra en la base de datos.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
       FROM productos
       WHERE nombre LIKE '%$buscar%'
         OR descripcion LIKE '%$buscar%'
         OR observaciones LIKE '%$buscar%' 
         OR palabras_clave LIKE '%$buscar%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

¿Alguien tendrá alguna solución ?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow Jonatan. Cuando creas la conexión tienes que setear la codificación a `utf-8`, de lo contrario es posible que te cambie las `ñ` por carácteres extraños y no encuentre las coincidencias. Por favor **[lee esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967)**, donde he tratado de abordar el tema en toda su amplitud. También debo decirte que tu consulta es vulnerable a la **Inyección SQL**. Para las consultas donde intervienen variables como `$buscar` es altamente recomendable usar consultas preparadas para evitar la inyección de código malicioso en el sistema.

Comment: amigo, con eso funciono, te agradezco tanto tu tiempo al leer mi post :)